# How to select AS2 in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, actionscript-2

I want to make my application compatible with as2, so I think what I want to do is only use the features that as2 provides, how to specify the compiler or source code that I only use the features in as2?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you only want to use AS2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AS3 and AS2 are not compatible. You have to choose whether you use AS3 or AS2 in your project.
However, currently, there is almost no point in writing new projects in AS2, because Flash Player 9 reaches 99% penetration rates, according to [Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/version_penetration.html)

So, start a new project in AS2 only if you desperately need it for some reason. In all other cases AS3 is your weapon of choice.

Comment: Yes, I have the reason to use AS2, you didn't answer my question how to use it instead AS3 :)

Comment: In that case you need to develop your project in AS2. You can do it either in Flash Professional IDE (not in Flex/Flash Builder), or using open-source AS2 compiler mtasc and develop in your editor of choice, like FlashDevelop.

Answer (score 1):

flex means only AS3 and higher. AS2 was earlier use inf flash for code behind. now even flash supports AS3 and as said earlier answers Adobe Virtual Machine for AS3 which is adobe flash 9 plugin/activex is widely deployed and you may no more need AS2

Answer (score 0):

AS3 is about 10 times more faster than AS2. AS2 will soon not be supported by many portals. AS2 libraries a decreasing in number, and resources are also discontinued. I'd go with AS3.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that sometimes there's no option to NOT support it.  Although as3 is at 99% penetration, that number doesn't reflect embedded devices.  And it is frequently the ONLY option.

Comment: How is this an answer? What does it provide that the accepted answer does not?

Answer (score 0):

The default compiler settings for Adobe Flex Builder are `-as3 = true` and `-es = false`.

The ECMAScript-3 compiler is an advanced option which bridges the gap significantly:

> Instructs the compiler to use the ECMAScript edition 3 prototype-based object model to allow dynamic overriding of prototype properties. In the prototype-based object model, built-in functions are implemented as dynamic properties of prototype objects.

To use the prototype object model, set the compiler accordingly, either:

- In the ActionScript file via the `ES` namespace:

  ```
  use namespace ES;
  ```
- In the compiler path via the flags:

  ```
  -as3 = false -es = true
  ```

The [dynamic keyword](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#dynamic) and a [namespace wrapper](http://blogs.adobe.com/bparadie/2012/01/14/wrapping-native-javascript-libraries-in-actionscript/) should be able to do the rest of the legwork, not accounting for API differences.

**References**

- [Wrapping native JavaScript libraries in ActionScript](http://blogs.adobe.com/bparadie/2012/01/14/wrapping-native-javascript-libraries-in-actionscript/)
- [Adobe Flex 4.6: About the application compiler options](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html)
- [History of ActionScript OOP Support](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3_Flex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f3f.html)`